# mermaid chart does not show in meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, mermaid

For some reason my [mermaid chart](http://knsv.github.io/mermaid/index.html#usage) does not show in a meteor page. I do see some SVG things in the dom but no chart is rendered...

[image]

```
 <div class="ui container mermaid">

graph TD;
    A-->B;
    A-->C;
    B-->D;
    C-->D;

            </div>

Template.APILogs.onRendered(function() {
    console.log('Test page! mermaid version'+mermaid.version());
    mermaid.initialize({startOnLoad:true});
});
```

Thanks so much for you help... I am missing something something very obvious here...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from the code samples you've shown, but since you're making your `mermaid.initialize` call in the `Template.APILogs` template's `onRendered` callback, you're binding it to that template. That means it will only initialize your mermaid charts within an associated `APILogs` template. Something like:

```
<template name="APILogs">
  <div class="ui container mermaid">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Make sure you've defined the `APILogs` template like the above.

Comment: Hi @hwillson, thank you again! Yes, I did what you suggested. I also received an answer from rob fallows here https://forums.meteor.com/t/sequence-diagram-in-meteor-cannot-read-property--actors-height-of-undefined/27956 he proposed to use the compatibility folder.